# Load Wordpress post without get_header() and get_footer()

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, magnific-popup

I'm developing a wordpress site where the posts are loaded in a popup with ajax (with [Magnific Popup](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/)). The posts are using the template `single.php`.

This works fine, except that the header and footer are also loaded in the popup (html tags, navigation, scripts, …). I can of course delete `get_header()` and `get_footer()` from the template, but then the single post pages aren't loaded correctly via permalinks.

I tried conditional tags, but when the template is loaded with Ajax, it doesn't 'see' it's loaded on the homepage.

I think working with different templates is an option, although I have seen sites that work with the same template (like the Zoo theme on themeforest). But I couldn't figure out how it works there.

So I'm stuck here. Anybody?

Comment: popup is not really desciptive enough, iframe or new dom element? I think if you are loading a entire page just to get the content is pretty slow, can you just not run your own custom ajax to pull the post content?

Comment: Not sure how to describe the popup; it's a [Magnific Popup](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/), and the content is loaded with ajax. The entire page is indeed loading, and that is exactly the question: how only to load the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clean solution would be to use the WordPress AJAX functions.

Themes are nowadays usually split in multiple parts to reuse blocks in various places. For example, the theme twentysixteen uses [`get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'single' );`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/) in the `single.php` to include the template file that shows the actual content of the file. You can use this easily to get the content of your post without header, footer etc.

First, set up the PHP part, you can just add this in the functions.php of your theme or directly in your plugin, dependant on what you are developing.

```php
<?php 
// for the admin area
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );
// for the public area
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );

function my_action_callback() {

    $postid = intval( $_POST['postid'] );
    $post = get_post( $postid );
    setup_postdata( $post );
    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'single' );

    wp_die(); // this is required to terminate immediately and return a proper response
}
```

The corresponding JavaScript part:

```
var data = {
    'action': 'my_action',
    'postid': 1234
};

// since 2.8 ajaxurl is always defined in the admin header and points to admin-ajax.php
// on the frontend you have to set it yourself
var ajaxurl = '<?=admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )?>';
jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
    // alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
    // response will now contain your post, without header, footer, sidebars etc.
});
```

`my_action` is the identifyer for the whole process and has to be consistent between the two parts.

Documentation for WordPress AJAX support: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: Thanks, now I understand how to pull only the content instead of the whole page without using another template or conditional tags. Although I don't really understand the code here, I'll try to implement it

Answer (score 1):

I finally found out that this option is included in the [Magnific Popup](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#ajax-type) plugin: "To modify content after it’s loaded, or to select and show just specific element from loaded file, there is a `parseAjax` callback".

But I'll accept the above answer as I think this is an elegant way, instead of loading the whole page and only show the part needed.